# Unity Prefab script is disabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, augmented-reality

My prefab has a script, however, every time it's being generated, the script is disabled. I've tried GetComponent().enable = true (not working) I've attached an image --> ([Prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gSEl.jpg)) and here's my code. FYI prefab is generated using the default UNET LobbyManager.

LobbyManager generates the prefab and I use a separate script to control the prefab. The script is attached to the prefab but when generated it's missing, therefore I've looked for the prefab and tried to attach it through the code.

```
GameObject imageTracker_1, imageTracker_2;
public GameObject[] user;
public GameObject myTextObj, origin, canvasUI;
public float distanceFromOrigin;


//public Text myText;

private void Awake()
{

    user[0] = GameObject.FindWithTag("Respawn");
    user[1] = GameObject.FindWithTag("Finish");

}

void Start()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        Destroy(this);
        return;
    }



    origin = GameObject.Find("PositionOrigin");
    //used for finding text, "GetComponent<Text>" needs to be attached or fails.
    canvasUI = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    //myText = canvasUI.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    // myText.text = "Out of area";
    myTextObj.SetActive(false);

    // we track the vuforia image within the scene and attach the avatar as a child               
    //imageTracker_1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Respawn");
    //GameObject imageTracker_2 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Finish");
    //transform.SetParent(imageTracker_1.transform, false);
    //transform.parent = imageTracker_1.transform;
}



private void Update()
{

    assigningAvatarToParent();

    distanceFromOrigin = Vector3.Distance(origin.transform.position, transform.position);

    //during start the gameObject will return NULL, this will make sure during every frame the gameObject does not equal null
    if (origin || imageTracker_1 || myTextObj == null)
    {
        myTextObj = GameObject.Find("OutOfBound");
        origin = GameObject.Find("PositionOrigin");
    }
}

void assigningAvatarToParent()
{
    int k = 0;
    while (k < user.Length){

        GameObject avatar = GameObject.Find("player_avatar" + k);
        avatar.transform.SetParent(user[k].transform, false);
        k++;
        Debug.Log("avatar for parents: " + avatar);

    }


    for (int a = 0; a < user.Length; a++)
    {

        GameObject avatar = GameObject.Find("player_avatar" + a);

        if (avatar.GetComponent<playerIdentity>() == null){
            avatar.AddComponent<playerIdentity>();

            origin = GameObject.Find("PositionOrigin");
            canvasUI = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
            myTextObj.SetActive(false);
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check if you had any errors? In newer versions of Unity, it automatically disables components that have errors.

Comment: You might also ask here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the link. 
@MoNarimani I've added an image, the script is not active. and the errors are just objects not being defined. But, I assume its because the script is inactive, therefore, I can't set the objects.

Comment: It looks like `myTextObj.SetActive(false);` will error because `myTextObj` is `null` in the inspector

Comment: the script is called during the runtime, removing that variable won't change anything. But thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the errors you are getting.

Comment: Just an aside, not sure if you assign `user` in the Inspector but if not, you don't allocate memory for it.

Comment: What class does your class inherits from? Maybe you are inheriting from a network class which disables itself when the player isn't a host?

Comment: There is no error, the script is not assigned to the prefabs generated. 
Yes @JavierBullrich, I inherit from NetworkBehaviour. I use if(!isLocalPlayer) so that all users have control of their own models/avatar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your script is derived from `NetworkBehaviour` - which afaik are disabled until there is an active connection to a server. Could this be the issue? (see the [UNet Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSceneObjects.html))

Also, when the Prefab is instantiated, your script deletes itself from it during the `Start()` function. That's why it's missing.

Calling `Destroy(this);` will remove the script component, but not delete the `GameObject` (and I've fallen into that trap about 100 times myself).

Not sure if that was your intent, since the LobbyManager is creating your Prefab. But if it is, you might want to use `DestroyImmediate(gameObject);` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes Until the user has an active connection, then the prefab is generated. The prefab has the script component but when generated it's lost. calling DestroyImmediate(gameObject); has deleted the prefab.

Comment: If I remove Destroy(); the script will be with every prefab but, the local users will not have control of the model.